# How to set session to the logged in user in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, web-config, session-timeout

I want to set `session time` for the user who sits idle without doing any work.

After a specific time when user comes again and works on that then it should redirect to login page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need session timeout. There are different ways to do that using ASP.NET MVC. Please, take a look on these tutorials and choose the way that fits better to you:

- [Handling Session and Authentication Timeouts in ASP.NET MVC](http://markfreedman.com/index.php/2012/02/28/handling-session-and-authentication-timeouts-in-asp-net-mvc/)
- [Handling Session Timeout Gracefully](http://www.fairwaytech.com/2012/01/handling-session-timeout-gracefully/)
- [Detecting Session Timeouts using a ASP.Net MVC Action Filter](http://www.tyronedavisjr.com/2008/11/23/detecting-session-timeouts-using-a-aspnet-mvc-action-filter/)